# Where should i put my rubygems after installation?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Suppose I installed some ruby gems using `gem install gemname`. Where should I install them, and when what directory should I run `gem install rubygems-update-1.3.1.gem` from?

Answer (score 1):

```
 gem env
```

will tell you where they were installed.
In general on windows it doesn't matter what directory you're in, running

```
 gem update --system
```

will work from anywhere.
-r

Answer (score 0):

They are automatically installed to your GEM_HOME. In Linux, you can open a terminal and type:

```
echo $GEM_HOME
```

To find out where that is exactly.

Comment: in windows how do i find and can i install gems from any directory in windows

Answer (score 0):

Is the place where you view your all gems list for linux.

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to be in any specific directory; running `gem install` will put the gem in the directory that `gem` expects your gems to be.

As mentioned in other answers, if you want to see where that directory is, run `gem env` and take a look at the `INSTALLATION DIRECTORY:` line.